# Send exact number of bytes over a socket

Tags: erlang, gen-tcp

I have read that in Erlang using gen_tcp the data sent over the socket can be aggregated in a single stream. How can i force the socket to send exactly a specific number of bytes?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve. The number of bytes sent will always be the number you specify. It won't ever not send bytes you asked it to send or send bytes you didn't ask it to send.

Comment: Am i wrong or actually or different send operations can be aggregated in a single chunk? {no_delay, false} should be standard behaviour

Comment: What do you mean by "a single chunk"? If you mean the amount of data you get in a single TCP read operation, it's arbitrary. This is a fundamental property of TCP and there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCP is a stream protocol (unlike UDP which is packet oriented) which e.g. means that the receiving application can't tell if the available data comes from one or several `send()` calls on the client.

You don't really have any control over the number of bytes being sent in a TCP packet, multiple `send()` calls may result in one TCP packet being received, and one `send()` call may result in several TCP packets being sent. This is controlled by the OS TCP stack.

In Erlang you can use the the socket option `{packet, 1|2|4}` to `gen_tcp:connect` and `gen_tcp:listen` to create a packet-oriented handling of the TCP data. This inserts a 1,2 or 4 bytes prefix to each `send()` and the receiving side (assuming it is also erlang and uses the same `{packet, N}` option) will read data until the sent number of bytes has been received, regardless of how the message was fragmented into TCP packets.

A call to `gen_tcp:recv` will block until the expected number of bytes has been read. And same for active mode sockets, the message is sent with the expected number of bytes.